# Join Multiple tables with access

Tags: ms-access, join

I have three tables in Access database. `CheckDJ` and `CashDJ` has more columns than `CashRJ`. I would like to merge those tables into one. I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    a.acctname,
    a.code,
    (
        sum(a.debit) + sum(b.debit) + sum(c.debit)
    ) AS DebitTotal,
    (
        sum(a.credit) + sum(b.credit) + sum(c.credit)
    ) AS CreditTotal
FROM
    (
        CheckDJ a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CashRJ b ON a.id = b.id
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN CashDJ c ON a.id = c.id
GROUP BY
    a.acctname,
    a.code
```

Problem is, the code above only display the similar data with `CheckDJ`. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will be great to post here some sample data from these tables and desired result (again as data).

Comment: What is meant by _similar data_

Comment: @GiladGreen the data that is the same with CheckDJ. The other data that I input to other tables that are not the same with CheckDJ doesn't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `acctname` and `code` are a primary key, select from a `UNION` query to include all records:

```
SELECT acctname, code, SUM(debit) As DebitTotal, SUM(credit) AS CreditTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT acctname, code, debit, credit, "CheckDJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CheckDJ 
    Union
    SELECT acctname, code, debit, credit, "CashRJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CashRJ 
    Union
    SELECT acctname, code, debit, credit, "CashDJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CashDJ 
)
GROUP BY acctname, code
```

Field `SoursTblName` is added in order to prevent uniting identical records from different tables into one.

---

If `CheckDJ` and `CashDJ`, or `CashRJ` may have in them identical records, use this query:

```
SELECT acctname, code, SUM(debitSum) As DebitTotal, SUM(creditSum) AS CreditTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT acctname, code, SUM(debit) As debitSum, SUM(credit) As creditSum, "CheckDJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CheckDJ 
    GROUP BY acctname, code
    Union
    SELECT acctname, code, SUM(debit) As debitSum, SUM(credit) As creditSum,  "CashRJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CashRJ 
    GROUP BY acctname, code
    Union
    SELECT acctname, code, SUM(debit) As debitSum, SUM(credit) As creditSum,  "CashDJ" As SoursTblName 
    FROM CashDJ 
    GROUP BY acctname, code
)
GROUP BY acctname, code
```

Comment: you query does not include the specified expression 'acctname' as part of an aggregate function. This is the error I got trying your code.

Comment: I'll modify the second sql

Comment: @Mai.V - I would appreciate it if you express your thanks by marking the answer as useful, and/of marking it as accepted ;)

Comment: Done. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I get your point, you shouldn't use group function. i.e.:

```
sum(a.credit) + sum(b.credit) + sum(c.credit)
```

and

```
sum(a.debit) + sum(b.debit) + sum(c.debit)
```

with this, you will get same amount for every record. Just add them together without any group function.

Comment: the `Left Join` limits the result set to `id`s in `CheckDJ`, other `id`s will not be summed up. The grouping is not an issue.

Comment: @Mai.V I edited the union query above, how dose it work now?